# Is there a way to terminate spot fleet instances automatically if Status Checks are failed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have been using EC2 spot fleet plugin with Jenkins and configured few spot request with that, however, there is a frequent problem I face where one or two of my spot instances fails at "Status Checks" and then Jenkins never picks them, therefore a lot of build wait to get a node.

The only solution I have here is to terminate those instances manually from the AWS Console. Is there any way I can set up or configure these instances to be terminated automatically?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no need for that to be done manually now. Spot instance itself has this feature enabled where they will be terminated if the Status Checks are failed.

This thing can be enabled while creating a spot request.

I have implemented a Spot Request with the `Stop Instance` feature instead of `Terminate` one (default).